# In R for a table, how to create new rows by substracting one row from another for each subject

Tags: r

So I have a table, d, that looks like this

```
id     trial    V1   V2  V3  V4
101      1       1    1   1   1
101      2       10   12  13  20
101      3       3    3   2   9
102      1       1    1   1   1 
102      2       10   12  11  11
102      3       9    8   7   6
103      1       1    1   1   1
103      2       2    3   4   5
103      3       11   12  13  14
 ...
```

And basically I need to create new rows, probably in a new table, that shows the difference between trial 3 and trial 1 for each Variable (V1, V2, V3, V4), maybe something like this:
If it's a new table:

```
id         V1   V2  V3  V4
101         2    2   1   8
102         8    7   6   5
103         10   12  13  14
...
```

i was thinking maybe using dplyr and aggregate it by id and have each column be the difference, but not sure if dplyr can do that so now I'm kinda stuck. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always have 1,2,3  trials in each id - you can define a function and use `summarize_each`in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
myfun <- function(x) { x[[3]]-x[[1]] }

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(myfun)) %>%
  select(-trial)


    id    V1    V2    V3    V4
  (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1   101     2     2     1     8
2   102     8     7     6     5
3   103    10    11    12     0
```

Comment: Something like that should do it. However, what if there is no trial 2 but there is a trial 3? I think trial `3` and `1` should be explicitly searched for rather than positional arguments.

Comment: @thelatemail I think some subjects have no trial 3, so if I have to search for trial 3 and trial 1 how would I go about to do that?

Comment: @KenLam - probably with something like `x[which(trial==3)] - x[which(trial==1)]`

Comment: @thelatemail there's no error when I run the code, but somehow the table returned is just all NA. Any idea? The value of the table is numeric for sure, and yes some rows are missing trial 1 and trial 3 but doesn't make sense that the whole table is just NA

Comment: @thelatemail Actually now I filtered out trial 2 first then used tail(x, 1) - x[[1]] and I don't have the NA problem, but now I have another problem which is that for some subject they only have trial one, and they are returning 0, is there a way to filter it in the function so that it performs the function if it's more than one row?